# como recorrer un arreglo recibido con SubmitHandler en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Buenos dias: tengo un array que recibo por el `SubmitHandler` de mi formulario

`attribute :  Array(2) 0 :  {value: '26'} 1 :  {value: '28'}`

Como ven hice un console y se ve perfectamente que tiene la estructura de un array. Pero este arra tengo que darle tratamiento en la funcion que dispara la accion al servidor antes de enviarlo y me esta pasando que no puedo recorrer este array usando un `map` y tampoco puedo hacer uso del `length` para saber mas informacion del array. Esta es la funcion donde intento trabajar sobre el arreglo. Estoy usando `TypeScript` y no he encontrado la forma para dar tipado a lo que viene en el data.

```
    const updateAttribute: SubmitHandler<Record<string, number>> = (data) => {

    console.log(data);

    setEditModal({ state: false, idx: null });
  };
```

Alguna idea que puede suceder

Comment: Agrega el  código del `map` que no te funciona y una foto de la consola abriendo el árbol de objetos/propiedades